# How to exclude a pattern when viewing app engine logs in the cloud console?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to exclude a string, or more generally a pattern from the app engine logs when I am auditing them in the app engine console.

I have tried the 'negative look ahead' solution described in [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) without success. Can someone post a working example?

Comment: It looks like this should work, I just tried this myself, it must be a bug in the console as it just stays on "Loading..." and never returns. I was using the regex:^((?!query).)*$ to filter out all rows containing the word "query". I have sent them feedback, i'll let update if I get a response.

Answer (score 5):

It appears this is now possible using the Advanced Search and combining operators with the `NOT` keyword. The simplest example is to use `NOT` before the text search expression:

```
resource.type="vpn_gateway"
"sending packet"
NOT "to 127.0.0.123"
```

This will search for vpn_gateway log entries containing the text "sending packet" and not containing the text "to 127.0.0.123"

More details is available in the [Advanced Logs Filters Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters#filter_summary).

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible using the below:

```
=~          # regular expression search for a pattern

!~          # regular expression search not for a pattern
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries).

Currently I have enabled slow_query_log in MySql and I'm using the below to exclude some of the values stored in the log:

```
-textPayload=~"SET timestamp="
-textPayload=~"# User@Host: root[root] @  [127.0.0.1]"
```

Here's an example of each of the textPayloads:

```
SET timestamp=1607853094;
# User@Host: root[root] @  [127.0.0.1]  thread_id:  3735  server_id: 14545446173
```

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to do a negative search using logs viewer in the Google Developer Console. However there is a workaround exporting logs to Google BigQuery, there you can run these regular expressions on Request logs (and not app logs).